# Monitor EDID gone, cant override P2350

Tags: display, dvi, edid

i have a P2350 Samsung 1080p monitor, but it is not recognised anymore in Windows, when connecting via DVI. In Ubuntu i at least get signal, but with wrong resolutions. So far i found out, that there must be something wrong with the edid.

The DVI must be on bus 3, because when i connect the with DVI and check with

```
i2cdump 3 0x50
```

i will get

```
     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f    0123456789abcdef
00: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff    ................
10: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff    ................
20: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff    ................
30: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff    ................
40: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff    ................
50: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff    ................
60: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff    ................
70: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff    ................
80: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff    ................
90: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff    ................
a0: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff    ................
b0: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff    ................
c0: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff    ................
d0: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff    ................
e0: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff    ................
f0: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff    ................
```

if i disconnect DVI it changes to

```
     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f    0123456789abcdef
00: XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX    XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
10: XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX    XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
20: XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX    XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
30: XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX    XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
40: XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX    XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
50: XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX    XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
60: XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX    XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
70: XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX    XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
80: XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX    XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
90: XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX    XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
a0: XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX    XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
b0: XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX    XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
c0: XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX    XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
d0: XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX    XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
e0: XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX    XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
f0: XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX    XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

So i guess i am on the right BUS = 3
Now i found a raw output of the same monitor on the internet and thought i could write it just in

```
sudo i2cset -y 3 0x50 0x00 0x00 b
sudo i2cset -y 3 0x50 0x01 0xFF b
sudo i2cset -y 3 0x50 0x02 0xFF b
...
```

but i does not change anything,

```
 i2cdump 3 0x50
```

stil delivers the same output, with all the ff ff...

Does anyone can help me with this?

Comment: Have you tried a new DVI cable?

Comment: Yes, i tried with hdmi<>dvi-cable, same issue.

Comment: Okay solved it!!! :) My monitor needed to be in service mode! To get into service mode, set brightness and contrast to 0, then keep pressing the "enter" button (4th from left) until "Service Function" menu pops up, now i2cset will work!

Comment: Great! Please read [Can I answer my own question?](http://superuser.com/help/self-answer). You might want to convert your comment into an answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

Okay solved it!!! :) My monitor needed to be in service mode! To get into service mode, set brightness and contrast to 0, then keep pressing the "enter" button (4th from left) until "Service Function" menu pops up, now i2cset will work! (this post is just to mark it as answered)